# Generate random numbers without duplicates in a dynamic array C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, random, dynamic-arrays

I want to randomize a dynamic array , with random numbers without duplicates in each column , and each column is limited ,

Check my main.c File

```
int main()
{
        int i, j;
        int **p;

        srand(time(0));

        p = malloc(9 * sizeof *p);
        for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
                p[i] = malloc (9 * sizeof *p[i]);
        }
        if (errno) {
                perror("startup");
                exit(1);
        }

        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
                for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
                        p[j][i] = random(j,i);
                }
        }

        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
                for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
                        printf(" %d ", p[j][i]);
                }
                printf ("\n");
        }
}
```

and this is my random function

```
int random(int *j, int *i)
{
int s = 0;
int b;
int MIN =0;
int MAX=0;
b= i;

switch (b)
{

    case 0:
            MAX = 9;
            MIN = 1;
            s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

    break;

case 1:
        MAX = 19;
        MIN = 10;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 2:
        MAX = 29;
        MIN = 20;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 3:
        MAX = 39;
        MIN = 30;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 4:
        MAX = 49;
        MIN = 40;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 5:
        MAX =59;
        MIN = 50;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 6:
        MAX = 69;
        MIN = 60;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 7:
        MAX = 79;
        MIN = 70;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

case 8:
        MAX = 90;
        MIN = 80;
        s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
    break;

}
return s;
}
```

so Now I want to have any other way to do it but I must use dynamic allocation 
please suggest me anything that can help me out .

Comment: What are you getting after compiling your code?

Comment: This `int random(int *j, int *i)` should really be `int random(int j, int i)`.

Comment: @haccks that's what I get http://prntscr.com/2auhee , I want the same result without the duplicates

Comment: Yes obviously since the same number in a very limited range is very likely to occur more than once. I suggest you read unwind's answer or add a simple check that the number hasn't been "picked" before. It's very inefficient though. Btw, `j` doesn't seem to have anything todo with your `random` function.

Comment: If you force no repeats, it's not really "random", right?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey No, that's not right.  No repeats arises in probability theory when you sample from a set without replacement, such as picking a sequence of cards from a deck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest some changes:

- Allocate the entire matrix with a single allocation, it's easier. It will mean that you must do the indexing manually (i.e. `matrix[y * width + x]`) but that's usually not too hard.
- It seems you have very tight requirements for the numbers to appear in each column. I would suggest pre-seeding the matrix with all the numbers in sequence, then *random shuffling*. It's often easier than eliminating dupes.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates there are two basic approaches - 1) shuffle the entire set and pick a suitable subset from the front, or 2) generate random values, reject and re-try if you get a duplicate.  Option 2 isn't as bad as it sounds if you're sampling only a few things from the range, but option 1 is easily the winner if the number of values is more than about square root of the range.

You can lose the switch statement.  Since your ranges are going up as multiples of `i`, just use that fact to determine the `MAX` and `MIN` values:

```
if (0 == i) {
  MIN = 1;
  MAX = 9;
} else {
  MIN = 10 * b;
  MAX = MIN + 9;
}
s = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a real random number generator that don't repeat numbers, that won't be random at all :-),

The best way to do it is to create a list as long as you need it, with the unrepeated random numbers you need and then put them in random order.

-- edit --

If you're generating X numbers from 1 to 99, I'd do the next algorithm:

- Generate the list of numbers from to 1 to 99, and put them on array N.
- for i = 1 to X, s = rand(S), take number s from array N
- Once you selected X different numbers from your array, you're done.

Do you think that'd work for you? It's easy, fast, and complies what you want.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2auhee Check that , I want to generate random numbers for a bingo card ! but in a column I don't want duplicates

Comment: @Faxsy just edited the answer, does that work for you?

Comment: I got your idea , but how to pick up a random number from the array N !

Comment: In array N the numbers are ordered, if you pick a number with a rand, and once picked you make it 0 or eliminate it from the list, the number won't be picked again and the final array with the X numbers will be in random order